# Maven profiling is just messy - other options?

Tags: java, maven, build, profile

We are using maven and to make thing easier we have started to use profiles. The problem is the it makes POM really messy hard to follow. Similar plugins executions are different profiles.

I am trying to use profiles for Dev, Stage and Production that will take care of everything - some of the things are similar and some different.

1. Can someone point me to a good tutorial about profiles (the one on the maven site is too abstract to be useful).
2. Is there other solution?

Comment: We've moved to gradle instead of maven. There's a lot less cruft and it's less verbose as well.

Comment: Migrating to Gradle is not an option unfortunately. Thanks